# Como definir "Check" em colunas com RepositoryItemCheckEdit

Tags: c#, gridview, devexpress

Tenho um `DataGrid` que algumas colunas são `CheckBox`, estou utilizando o método `RepositoryItemCheckEdit` da DevExpress para fazer isso:

Porém, como faço para fazer um `Check`? sei que preciso usar a propriedade `gridView1.SetRowCellValue`, porém mesmo definindo o valor como `true` o `CheckBox` da coluna permanece `Uncheck`

Estou com o mesmo problema que neste link: [RepositoryItemCheckEdit doesn't stay checked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16150249/repositoryitemcheckedit-doesnt-stay-checked) mas mesmo assim não consegui resolver.

Código do `RepositoryItemCheckEdit`

```
private void check_column()
    {
        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit acessar_select = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

        gridView1.Columns["ACESSAR"].ColumnEdit = acessar_select;

        acessar_select.ValueChecked = true;
        acessar_select.ValueUnchecked = false;
        acessar_select.AllowGrayed = false;
        acessar_select.CheckStyle = CheckStyles.Standard;
        acessar_select.NullStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.StyleIndeterminate.Unchecked;

        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit inserir_select = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

        gridView1.Columns["INSERIR"].ColumnEdit = inserir_select;

        inserir_select.ValueChecked = true;
        inserir_select.ValueUnchecked = false;
        inserir_select.AllowGrayed = false;
        inserir_select.CheckStyle = CheckStyles.Standard;
        inserir_select.NullStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.StyleIndeterminate.Unchecked;

        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit editar_select = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

        gridView1.Columns["EDITAR"].ColumnEdit = editar_select;

        editar_select.ValueChecked = true;
        editar_select.ValueUnchecked = false;
        editar_select.AllowGrayed = false;
        editar_select.CheckStyle = CheckStyles.Standard;
        editar_select.NullStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.StyleIndeterminate.Unchecked;

        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit excluir_select = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

        gridView1.Columns["EXCLUIR"].ColumnEdit = excluir_select;

        excluir_select.ValueChecked = true;
        excluir_select.ValueUnchecked = false;
        excluir_select.AllowGrayed = false;
        excluir_select.CheckStyle = CheckStyles.Standard;
        excluir_select.NullStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.StyleIndeterminate.Unchecked;

        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit imprimir_select = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();

        gridView1.Columns["IMPRIMIR"].ColumnEdit = imprimir_select;

        imprimir_select.ValueChecked = true;
        imprimir_select.ValueUnchecked = false;
        imprimir_select.AllowGrayed = false;
        imprimir_select.CheckStyle = CheckStyles.Standard;
        imprimir_select.NullStyle = DevExpress.XtraEditors.Controls.StyleIndeterminate.Unchecked;
    }
```

Código que preenche os dados (consulta ao banco):

```
private void preenche_form(string iduser)
    {
        Classes.Datatable.Datatable_permissoes dat_permis = new Classes.Datatable.Datatable_permissoes();

        DataTable retorno = dat_permis.preenche_permis(iduser);

        DataTableReader dtr = retorno.CreateDataReader();

        if (dtr.HasRows)
        {
            while (dtr.Read())
            {
                string tela = dtr["roleid"].ToString();
                string[] Linha = tela.Split('.');

                string expression = ("id = " + "'" + Linha[0] + "'").ToString();

                DataRow[] index = ret_permi.Select(expression);

                int t = ret_permi.Rows.IndexOf(index[0]);

                if(Linha[1] == "1")
                {

                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(t, gridView1.Columns["ACESSAR"], true);
                }
                else if (Linha[1] == "2")
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(t, gridView1.Columns["INSERIR"], true);
                }
                else if (Linha[1] == "3")
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(t, gridView1.Columns["EDITAR"], true);
                }
                else if (Linha[1] == "4")
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(t, gridView1.Columns["EXCLUIR"], true);
                }
                else if (Linha[1] == "5")
                {
                    gridView1.SetRowCellValue(t, gridView1.Columns["IMPRIMIR"], true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Tela:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**EDIÇÂO**

Apôs pequisa na internet, consegui fazer o `Check`, porém ao clicar em uma celula, ele `Check` em todas da linha:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, depois de muita luta e passar o dia atras de uma resposta, consegui fazer.

O segredo está que para cada coluna, será necessário um `Dictionary` (obs. eu usei `Dictionary` mas pode ser `List` e similares).

Então eu criei um dicionario `checkedMap` para a coluna `ACESSAR` e um `check_inserir` para a coluna `INSERIR`

E defini o evento abaixo em:

```
this.gridView1.CustomUnboundColumnData += new DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventHandler(this.gridView1_ACESSAR);
```

Então:

```
 readonly Dictionary<object, bool> checkedMap = new Dictionary<object, bool>();
    readonly Dictionary<object, bool> check_inserir = new Dictionary<object, bool>();

    private void gridView1_ACESSAR(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.CustomColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.IsGetData && e.Column.FieldName == "ACESSAR")
        {
            bool check;

            if (checkedMap.TryGetValue(e.Row, out check))
            {
                e.Value = check;
            }
        }
        else if (e.IsGetData && e.Column.FieldName == "INSERIR")
        {
            bool check;

            if (check_inserir.TryGetValue(e.Row, out check))
            {
                e.Value = check;
            }
        }


        if (e.IsSetData && e.Column.FieldName == "ACESSAR")
        {
            var check = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);

            if (checkedMap.ContainsKey(e.Row))
            {
                checkedMap.Remove(e.Row);
            }

            checkedMap.Add(e.Row, check);
        }
        else if (e.IsSetData && e.Column.FieldName == "INSERIR")
        {
            var check = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);

            if (check_inserir.ContainsKey(e.Row))
            {
                check_inserir.Remove(e.Row);
            }

            check_inserir.Add(e.Row, check);
        }
    }
```